# Change textbox background colour according to value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form with textboxes and dropdown for each row. I would like to change the background colour of the textboxes of that particular row when I select 'Absent' from the dropdown of the relative field. I am using javascript which works fine but only with the first row:

```
<script>

function changeBack() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("attendance_status");
    var textbx = document.getElementById("stname");
    var textbxsur = document.getElementById("stsurname");
    if (inputVal.value == "0") {
        textbx.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        textbxsur.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    else{
        textbx.style.backgroundColor = "";
        textbxsur.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
}

changeBack();

</script>
```

The table is being generated via php as follows:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM `b10_18591250_JC`.`STUDENT` WHERE `ST_GROUP` = $st_group");
   $result = mysql_query($query);

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{

 echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=stid[] readonly type=number class=form-control value=" .$row['ID']." </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=stname id=stname readonly type=text class=form-control value=" .$row['NAME']." </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=stsurname id=stsurname readonly type=text  class=form-control value=" .$row['SURNAME']." </td>";

echo "<td>";
echo "<select class=form-control name=attendance_status[] id=attendance_status onchange='changeBack()'>";
echo "<option value=1>Present</option>";
echo "<option value=0>Absent</option>";
echo "</select>";

echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>"; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample using jQuery,  may be useful for you :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Status</td>
        </tr>
        <?php for($i=1; $i<4; $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $i ?></td>
            <td><?= 'Name'.$i ?></td>
            <td><select><option value="p">Present</option><option value="a">Absent</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').change(function() {
            if($(this).val() == 'a') {
                $(this).css('background-color','#F00');
                $(this).parent().parent().css('background-color','#F00');
            } else {
                $(this).css('background-color','#FFF');
                $(this).parent().parent().css('background-color','#FFF');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using id, id should unique, it should not repeat, but in your code for every select box, same id is assigned (in while loop), so it will change the styling of the first occurrence of the element with the id **attendance_status**. Use class instead of the id in such cases.

The use of id is to optimize search algorithm to find only one element as soon as it finds an element with the given id it stops searching further, So it will not have any effect on other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Change id to class. When you use Id your code take only first element.

```
var inputVal = document.getElementsByClassName("attendance_status");
var textbx = document.getElementsByClassName("stname");
var textbxsur = document.getElementsByClassName("stsurname");
```